# Mismatched types error when moving a method from a trait implementation to a trait definition

Tags: rust

I have two structs, `VM` and `Word`. I need a new struct `Control` which behaves just like `VM`, but with one more field `master`. Because Rust has no inheritance, I try to extend the struct through composition. I move the functions of `VM` into a new trait `Core`, and implement `Core` for `Control`. The resulting code works.

```
struct Word<T> {
  action: fn(target: &T)
}

struct VM {
  word: Word<VM>
}

trait Core<T> {
  fn word(&self) -> &Word<T>;
  fn hello(&self) { println!("Hello"); }
  fn execute(&self);
}

impl Core<VM> for VM {
  fn word(&self) -> &Word<VM> { &self.word }
  fn execute(&self) { (self.word().action)(self); }
}

struct Control {
  word: Word<Control>,
  master: i32,
}

impl Core<Control> for Control {
  fn word(&self) -> &Word<Control> { &self.word }
  fn execute(&self) { (self.word().action)(self); }
}

fn main() {
  let vm = VM{
    word: Word {action: Core::hello}
  };
  vm.execute();
  let control = Control{
    word: Word {action: Core::hello},
    master: 0,
  };
  vm.execute();
}
```

The two implementation of `execute` are identical. So I move `execute` into trait `Core`.

```
trait Core<T> {
  fn word(&self) -> &Word<T>;
  fn hello(&self) { println!("Hello"); }
  fn execute(&self) { (self.word().action)(self); }
}

impl Core<VM> for VM {
  fn word(&self) -> &Word<VM> { &self.word }
}

impl Core<Control> for Control {
  fn word(&self) -> &Word<Control> { &self.word }
}
```

Which compiles with the following error:

```
main.rs:14:44: 14:48 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&T`,
    found `&Self`
(expected type parameter,
    found Self) [E0308]
main.rs:14   fn execute(&self) { (self.word().action)(self); }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Thanks for correcting my poor English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you move execute in `Core`, there is nothing in the trait definition that says that `T` is the same type as `Self`.

```
trait Core<T> {
  fn word(&self) -> &Word<T>;
  fn hello(&self) { println!("Hello"); }
  fn execute(&self) { 
      (self.word() // this is a &Word<T>
          .action) // this is a fn(T)
          (self);  // this type is Self. T is not necessarily = Self
  }
}
```

When `execute` is in the `impl Core<Control> for Control`, the impl says that `Self` and `T` are both = `Control`, so `execute` works. But if T can be anything like in the definition of the trait, Rust can't let your code compile.

How to fix it depends on what you need to do.

If your trait is always meant to be implemented this way (`impl Core<Something> for Something` or `impl Core<SomethingElse> for SomethingElse` but NEVER as `impl Core<Something> for SomethingElse`), you can drop the parameter from the trait definition and have just:

```
trait Core: Sized {
  fn word(&self) -> &Word<Self>; // now you can't parametrize what 
                                 // Word to return. It will be Self.
  fn hello(&self) { println!("Hello"); }
  fn execute(&self) { (self.word().action)(self); } // ...and this works
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I need.